# (TeleBot на Python) Как сделать пошагового диалогового бота в тг?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Я раньше никогда не разрабатывал ботов, так что это буквально мой первый раз, просьба не судить строго.

В общем, я делаю типа "игрового" бота. Все взаимодействия, события и тому подобное, абсолютно всё будет делаться через текст. Однако, возникла огромная проблема, из-за которой бот порой может даже ломаться. Проблема заключается в том, что игрок может "перескочить" определённые моменты, что ломает логическую цепочку. Вот например: прописываем `/start`, бот нас приветствует и далее, у нас появляется кнопка "Начать играть"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия кнопки "Начать играть", бот нам выдаёт *условную* сумму денег и *условный* голод, который нужно периодически пополнять, покупая шаурму.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, игрок может НЕ нажимая на кнопку старта игры, вручную прописать "Купить шаурму" и тем самым, "перескочить" и нарушить логику. У него ещё нет ни голода, ни денег, а он уже покупает что-то. Как это исправить? Помогите пожалуйста!
P.S. не исключено, что код я пишу как-то неправильно, ведь это мой 1-ый раз.

Код оказался слишком большой и не отображался корректно, поэтому вот файл с кодом: [ФАЙЛ](https://www.mediafire.com/file/xkerx5v94aerqj7/TGBOT.py/file)

Работа (как по мне) реально большая, поэтому аж стыдно тревожить по такому поводу, ещё раз сорри, но правда нужна помощь. В интернете, к сожалению, не нашёл ничего похожего с решением.

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее!!!!!!!